# Android ListView getting changed when resumed

Tags: android, android-listview, runtime-error

I'm using this in onCreate.

```java
    /************* Create Custom Adapter on Thread ************/

    adapter=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

This is my Asynctask class,

```java
class Asyntax extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    LoadingDialog lDialog=new LoadingDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        lDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            setListData();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String st) {
        super.onPostExecute(st);
        lDialog.dismiss();
        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        AdListener googleAdListener = new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                try {
                    addMob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        mAdView.setAdListener(googleAdListener);
    }
}
```

The method setListData takes value from json each time the activity is called. If I change the json data(by performing task in another activities, trying to make a game) and hit home button to pause it, when I resume the screen only one row is shown in the list(the one having data changed). Please tell me where might have been I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to use onStop() and onResume() methods of Activty class.

In onStop() you can save the adapter's data and in onResume() you can set the data.